# what is the preparation of before apply for ads?

Tags: advertising

I have built a new site(finished last week, but no SEO, no clients). I know apply for ads need a long time. So I send my request to google adsense, and then do the `SEO`, send my site to web search. but yesterday I received an e-mail:

`Thank you for your interest in Google AdSense. Unfortunately, after reviewing your application, we're unable to accept you into Google AdSense at this time.`

what is the preparation of before apply for ads? Am I ignore something must do before apply for ads?

And how to apply `Google doubleclicks`? Or other ads service? I am newer for apply for ads. can anyone recommend me some good ads service? Thanks.

Comment: "showed that the [???] It is not possible" ... is this the message exactly as it appeared? (If not, can you include the entire message from AdSense?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Google AdSense help

**How can I help make sure my application will be approved?**

http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75109